# Multiple resultsets when used recursion in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, recursion, mysql-5.7

```
    CREATE TABLE category(category_id int,  name varchar(255),  parent int);
    
    INSERT INTO category VALUES(1, 'ELECTRONICS', NULL);
    INSERT INTO category VALUES (2, 'TELEVISIONS', 1);
    INSERT INTO category VALUES (3, 'TUBE', 2);
    INSERT INTO category VALUES (4, 'LCD' , 2);
    INSERT INTO category VALUES (5, 'PLASMA', 2);
    INSERT INTO category VALUES (6, 'PORTABLE ELECTRONICS', 1);
    INSERT INTO category VALUES (7, 'MP3 PLAYERS', 6);
    INSERT INTO category VALUES (8, 'FLASH' , 7);
    INSERT INTO category VALUES (9, 'CD PLAYERS' , 6);
    INSERT INTO category VALUES (10, '2 WAY RADIOS', 6);
    INSERT INTO category VALUES (11, 'CURVE', 5);

CREATE PROCEDURE `test`.`store_procedure_name`(IN cat_id INT)
BEGIN
    declare loopId Int;
    declare lv varchar(100);
    SET max_sp_recursion_depth = 255;
    IF(select count(category_id) from category where parent=cat_id) > 0 THEN 
    CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS temp_category_table (
      `id` smallint(5) unsigned,
      `status` tinyint(3)
      ) ENGINE=InnoDB ;
    INSERT INTO temp_category_table
    (id, status) 
    VALUES (cat_id, 0); -- this could be multiple insertions too(could use a join to another table)
          
    WHILE (select count(id) from temp_category_table where status=0) > 0 DO 
      set loopId = (select id from temp_category_table where status=0 limit 1);
      
      INSERT INTO temp_category_table
      (id, status)                                       
      (select category_id, 0 from category where parent=loopId);
      
      update temp_category_table set status=1 where id=loopId;
      CALL store_procedure_name_3((select id from temp_category_table where status=0 limit 1));     
    END WHILE;
    (select DISTINCT id from temp_category_table order by id );
    END IF;
   
END
```

When called `CALL store_procedure_name(2)` 2 result sets are coming. May I know how to restrict that to only 1. Because I have a large table and can be expected very deep hierarchical structure.
Also is there any alternative for `max_sp_recursion_depth` . Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1):

One way may be to record the recursion depth to restrict the output. To do so, we could pass a parameter `recursion_depth` to the procedure, and +1 at the beginning and -1 at the end.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `store_procedure_name` -- ##### Remove `test`
    (IN cat_id INT, recursion_depth INT) -- ##### add recursion depth
BEGIN
    declare loopId Int;
    declare lv varchar(100);
    SET max_sp_recursion_depth = 255;
    SET recursion_depth = IFNULL(recursion_depth + 1, 0); -- ##### Depth + 1
    
    IF(select count(category_id) from category where parent=cat_id) > 0 THEN 
    CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS temp_category_table (
      `id` smallint(5) unsigned,
      `status` tinyint(3)
      ) ENGINE=InnoDB ;
    INSERT INTO temp_category_table
    (id, status) 
    VALUES (cat_id, 0);
    
    WHILE (select count(id) from temp_category_table where status=0) > 0 DO 
      set loopId = (select id from temp_category_table where status=0 limit 1);
      INSERT INTO temp_category_table
      (id, status)                                       
      (select category_id, 0 from category where parent=loopId);
      
      update temp_category_table set status=1 where id=loopId;
      CALL store_procedure_name -- ##### remove '_3'
          ((select id from temp_category_table where status=0 limit 1), 
          recursion_depth); -- #### Input current recursion depth
    END WHILE;
    IF recursion_depth=1 THEN -- ##### Restrict output at level 1
        (select DISTINCT id from temp_category_table order by id );
    END IF; -- #####
    END IF;
   SET recursion_depth = recursion_depth - 1; -- ###### Depth - 1
END;

CALL store_procedure_name(2, 0); -- ##### Input recursion depth at 0
```

[Code link](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=d15178fe848f40cb7fce81f352d1cab8)